# determine where $f_x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

$f(x,y)=$\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/3}} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} \\ \\
\end{array}

I know how to compute $f_x$(when $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$):
$f_x=\frac{2x(2x^2+4y^2)}{3(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}}$

Also I know that using the definition: $ f_x(0,0)=0$

but I have a hard time understanding what the next steps are

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with continuity, but it seems to me that (0,0) is the only point where it is not continuous. I think it is only discontinuous when the denominator is zero, and (0,0) are the only real x and y values that make the denominator be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}h^{1/3} = 0$$ Now, if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ is clearly continuous as a composition of continuous functions. So we have to check continuity as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$. We may use polar-coordinates to check this. Thus $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{4x(x^2+2y^2)}{3(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}} = \frac{4}{3}\lim_{r \to 0^+}r^{1/3}\cos\varphi(\cos^2\varphi + 2\sin^2\varphi)= 0$$ Hence $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ is continuous for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You forgot the denominator in the last equality.

Comment: Just edited. That was dumb.